Creating a WearOS app starting from existing Flutter app
I have an existing flutter app and now I want to create a WearOS version of it. I am quite not sure how can I handle this. I already have the main structure of the app organized in folders (app_controller, configuration, core, view). I have mostly 2 doubts:

Do I have to create a new entire project?
Is there a way to render the UI depending on if the device is a phone or a watch?

The app is quite big and I didn't find any example on the internet about this issue. Any example would be great!
EDIT: I have the app config for different flavours (dev, prod, release). Is there a way that the code detect which device is running the app and display a different view for each device?
Thanks all!

I don't think currently there is a support to use Flutter UI to build the wearOS app, so if your app is built using Flutter, you probably won't be able to use your existing code.

I found an article https://medium.com/@Toglefritz/create-a-cross-platform-flutter-app-for-android-and-wear-os-and-others-267d142867c0 -- here he uses LayoutBuilder to calculate device size and build the UI, but my project is quite huge and it would be a massive amount of work changing everything, that's why I was asking for something more suitable
